# Union of open sets with bounded, nonempty complement

Tags: real-analysis

Let $U_1 \subseteq U_2 \cdots$ be open sets and assume that each of these sets has  bounded, nonempty complement. Prove that $\cup_{j} U_j \neq \mathbb{R}$

This is an exercise problem from the section perfect set in my real analysis textbook. It is intuitively true to me since as $i$ tends to $\infty$, the complement of $U_i$ is still nonempty. However I don't see why the condition that it is bounded is useful and have difficulty writing down a rigorous proof. Also I am not using anything related to perfect set. Can someone help me please. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to showing that the intersection of the complements is nonempty. The complement of each $U_i$ is closed and bounded, and if you already have access to the Heine-Borel theorem, then you know these are compact sets. Then you can apply the [Cantor intersection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

The boundedness is useful and necessary because when
$$U_n = (- \infty , n)$$
we have $$\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N}U_n = \mathbb R$$